# How to run WebView.mainFrame.loadRequest synchronously?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, webview, nsrunloop

In my app I'm trying to navigate to a given URL using a WebView (non visible). However, loading web content happens asynchronously. For later processing I need this however to wait until all web content is loaded (including redirections).

I experimented with `CFRunLoopRunInMode` to make it wait (or timeout) but cannot get it to work properly with the available loop modes. With `kCFRunLoopDefaultMode` no redirection is done and the load request stops with the first address. The mode `kCFRunLoopCommonModes` even crashs after the load request (swift code, so I don't have any useful error information).

I have registered my class as frame load delegate so I know when everything is loaded (even after multiple redirections). I just need make it work while a run loop is active (it works nicely without). Code:

```
  override func webView(sender: WebView!, didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
    jsLogger.logInfo("==> Start loading");
  }

  override func webView(sender: WebView!, willPerformClientRedirectToURL URL: NSURL!,
    delay seconds: NSTimeInterval, fireDate date: NSDate!, forFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
      redirecting = true;
  }

  override func webView(sender: WebView!, didCreateJavaScriptContext context: JSContext, forFrame: WebFrame!) {
    jsLogger.logInfo("==> JS create");
  }

  override func webView(sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
    if redirecting {
      redirecting = false;
      return;
    }

    jsLogger.logInfo("==> Navigating to: " + sender.mainFrameURL);
  }

  override func webView(sender: WebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!, forFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
    jsLogger.logError("Navigating to webpage failed with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
```

And here the code to load a URL with the runloop:

```
  func navigateAndWait(location: String) -> String {
    if let url = NSURL(string: location) {
      redirecting = false;
      webClient.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url));

      let result: Int = Int(CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 10, Boolean(0)));
      switch result {
      case kCFRunLoopRunFinished:
        return "Invalid run loop";

      case kCFRunLoopRunTimedOut:
        return "Call timed out";

      case kCFRunLoopRunStopped:
        fallthrough;

      default: // Everything ok.
        return "";
      }
    }
    return "Invalid URL";

  }
```

What other ways exist to make my thread wait for the load request to finish?

Note: a solution can be given for both Obj-C and Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `performSelector:onThread:` in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` and `didFailLoadWithError:` to perform any task you want when the webview finishes load.